# Фильтрация получаемых данных с mysql на jsp и помещение данных в сообщение и рассылка на майл

Tags: java, mysql

Есть база данных, таблица `project_status_hist` содержит свое ID, `user_Id` связанное с таблицей юзеров, `project_iD` с таблицей проектов. Соответственно, `old_projectstatus_id` и `new_projectstatus_id`  связана с таблицей статусов проектов (старый и новый).

Т.е в таблице хранятся данных о изменениях статуса проекта, как только юзер поменяет статус проекта с одного на другой в таблицу заносятся данные, а статусы (по типу закрыт, открыт, заморожен).

Создал сервлет вот код:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import dao.DatabaseDAO;
import dev.employee.Employee;
import phones.phones;
import project.status.history.ProjectStatusHist;
import user.User;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ProjectStatusChange
 */
@WebServlet("/servlet/project/ProjectStatusChange")
public class ProjectStatusChange extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContReportJobsByUserProjectsMailing.class);

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ProjectStatusChange() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        logger.debug("Start ProjectStatusChange");

        DatabaseDAO dao = new DatabaseDAO();

        try {
            Collection<ProjectStatusHist> ProjectStatusHist = dao.getAll(ProjectStatusHist.class);
            req.setAttribute("ProjectStatusHist", ProjectStatusHist);   

            dao.close();
        }

         catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();           
        }
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/dev/views/Test/test.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Он выводит все данные из таблицы в jsp, мне нужно отфильтровать данные чтобы выводило только допустим если старый статус был закрыт и изменен на любой другой, плюс эту информацию поместить в сообщение и отправить по майлу. Либо можно как-то сделать это без jsp просто в сервлете? Не понимаю как. Код  jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>




<table border="3" width="100%" >
<tr>        <th>№</th>
            <th>Пользователь</th> 
            <th>Старый статус</th>
            <th>Новый статус</th>
            <th>Дата</th>

     </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${ProjectStatusHist}"  var="ProjectStatusHist">

        <tr>
            <td> ${ProjectStatusHist.id} </td> 
            <td> ${ProjectStatusHist.user.name} </td>
            <td> ${ProjectStatusHist.oldProjectStatus.name} </td> 
           <td> ${ProjectStatusHist.newProjectStatus.name} </td> 
           <td> ${ProjectStatusHist.actionDate} </td>


        </tr> 
    </c:forEach>


</table>
```

Comment: а где у вас происходит смена статуса записи?

Comment: Так, по поводу фильтрации, вы можете в своем DAO сделать метод, который вернет Вам отфильтрованный список по заданным критериям. По поводу отправки письма, надо встроиться в место где физически в коде происходит смена статусов записей. JSP к этому никак не относится, она лишь отображает данные, пришедшие с сервера.

Comment: Хорошо. Как сейчас у Вас работает метод `getAll()` в классе `DatabaseDAO`?

Comment: Т.е. Вам нужно выбрать только те записи у которых предыдущий статус == "Закрыт" ? А в БД Вы как ходите? jdbc, hibernate, jpa ?

Comment: Читайте тогда документацию по Hibernate, как описывать правильно запросы при помощи HQL, как разберетесь, сможете написать метод в DAO, который вернет Вам список отфильтрованный по Вашим критериям.